# How to use liferay-ddm:template-selector tag for custom Entity in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

When  using `<liferay-ddm:template-selector>` tag  which configuration to do for this tag? And how we can all attributes value of this tag  for our customer database entity.

I also tried, but no ADT list will be displayed which is created for custom Entity.
Please help me to do correct configuration for custom entity ADT Template list display using `<liferay-ddm:template-selector>`.

Comment: Did you follow these steps? https://dev.liferay.com/ca/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/implementing-application-display-templates And where did you put the tag?

Comment: I want to put this tag in my custom portlet custom configuration.jsp  file

Comment: the tutorial should be self-describing. make sure that you are not misplacing the permissions definitions. it is a common mistake to put the default XML in a different folder as configured.